# Creating a new object from a form in a Modal in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to create a new object from a form in a modal populated with the form data.

This works for the name, but not for the img (currently 'img' is just set to render text on screen, I'll work on making it upload an actual image later, but I'm trying to get multiple form inputs to populate to a new record.

I'm thinking I didn't set up the onChange portion correctly?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addContact } from '../actions/contactActions';
import {
  Button,
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input
} from 'reactstrap'
import uuid from 'uuid';

class ContactModal extends Component {
  state = {
    modal: false,
    name: '',
    img: ''
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal
    });
  }

  onChangeName = (e) => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }

  onChangeImg = (e) => {
    this.setState({[e.target.img]: e.target.value})
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newContact = {
      id: uuid(),
      name: this.state.name,
      img: this.state.img
    }

    this.props.addContact(newContact);

    this.toggle();

    }

    render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <Button
            style={{marginBottom: '.5rem'}}
            onClick={this.toggle}
            className="policyadd"
            >Add New Contact
          </Button>
          <Modal
            isOpen={this.state.modal}
            toggle={this.toggle}
            >
            <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>
              Add A New Contact
            </ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody>
              <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

                <FormGroup>
                  <Label for="name">Name</Label>
                  <Input
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    id="name"
                    placeholder="Add name of new contact"
                    onChange={this.onChangeName}
                    />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                  <Label for="img">link to image</Label>
                  <Input
                    type="text"
                    name="img"
                    id="img"
                    placeholder="Add path to image"
                    onChange={this.onChangeImg}
                    />
                </FormGroup>
                <Button
                  className="policyadd"
                  style={{marginTop: '1rem'}}
                  block
                  >Add Contact
                </Button>
              </Form>
            </ModalBody>
          </Modal>
        </div>

      )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  contact: state.contact
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {addContact})(ContactModal)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I needed to change the e.target.img to e.target.name, it's looking at the target's name, which is img.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach to iterate over form elements, extract their values and create your own object. Then, do whatever you like with your object:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const form = event.target;
    const data = new FormData(form);
    for (let name of data.keys()) {
      const input = form.elements[name];
      console.log(input);
      console.log('value:', input.value);
    }
    
  }

    render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <label>Name: <input name="name" type="text" /></label><br />
              <label>Image: <input name="img" type="text" /></label><br />
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="root" />
```